# How do I "multiple" Laravel App best practice

Tags: laravel, wildcard-subdomain

I have a Laravel App running which shall be cloned for multiple customers, what is the best way to handle this?

Of course I could clone the app and create for each new customer a new Webpage and add the database etc.

But I do not like the fact that I have to update each clone if I add changes to the application.

I would like to solve this with some sort of admin panel so if a user logs into the app (app.dev) the server checks wether the user belongs to app one and redirects him to one.app.dev, so that I "only" have to change some constants and update database.

Any tips or ideas how to Approach this?

Comment: Have you considered creating a laravel package?

Comment: @thisiskelvin no can you explain me how that would help me please

Comment: Take a look at this doc page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages

Comment: What you're describing is known as multi-tenancy. Being able to have a single codebase that functions for a number of clients, while keeping clear separation. Take a look at some of the multi-tenancy packages that are built for Laravel like [this](https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant) and [this](https://github.com/tenancy/tenancy).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the needs of the customers, if all customers are using the same code base. For example CRUD for pages and news, you can distribute this logic in a package lik Jon said.

If you would like one central code base, you should relate your data to customers (pages and news belong to one customer). So one.app.dev will only show pages and news from customer one.

The last option you can solve by one central db, our by using a [multi tenancy](https://laravel-tenancy.com/) setup.